# How can i create common xib for all ipads and iphones without creating seprate xibs for iphone and ipad? Not storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xib

Current xib's showing layout issues while switching between devices. I need single xibs which support all ios devices instead of using storyboard.

Comment: You can use Adaptive Layout to use a single XIB for iPhone and iPad both.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xcode 7.3 and above you can vary the constraints based on size class

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Size-ClassSpecificLayout.html

for xcode 8 there are some updation but underlying concept is size class , please check this

http://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/

https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reponse. Im using Xcode 8.2 with objective c i will check and let you know.

Comment: @lj999 please accept the answer if it helps you thanks

Comment: Its not working. It is  almost compatible with iphone series, when i switch to ipad it will be a mess.

Comment: There must be something wrong in your implementation , size class regular/regular stands for ipad make sure the contraints are correct .